# Google maps for android - markers not showing

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm creating a MapFragment in android; maps is showing just fine (although it takes 10 seconds to open), but no marker is shown.

This is the code of the fragment:

```
public class VehiclesMapFragment extends MapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback  {

GoogleMap _map;

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

    if (_map == null) {

        _map = this.getMap();
        //_map = this.getMap();
        //if (_map != null) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ReDrawList(_vehicles);
            }
        }, 2000);
        //}
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    _map = googleMap;


    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ReDrawList(_vehicles);
        }
    }, 10000);

}



public VehiclesMapFragment() {

}

VehiclesPosition[] _vehicles = null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    _vehicles = (VehiclesPosition[])getArguments().getSerializable("VEHICLES");

    //setUpMapIfNeeded();

}



public void ReDrawList(VehiclesPosition[] vehicles)
{
    if (vehicles != null && vehicles.length > 0 && _map != null) {

        LatLngBounds bounds = null;
        for (VehiclesPosition vp : vehicles) {
            LatLng latlngPos = vp.GetMapLatLng();

            if (bounds == null)
                bounds = new LatLngBounds(latlngPos, latlngPos);
            else
                bounds = bounds.including(latlngPos);

            MarkerOptions mi = vp.GetMapMarker();
            Marker mm = _map.addMarker(mi);
            mm.showInfoWindow();

        }

        try{
            _map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));
            _map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds,100));
        }catch (Exception exx) {

        }
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_vehicles_map, container, false);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    return v;
}



@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    //setUpMapIfNeeded();

    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()+ " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}

}
```

and this is the layout file:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/map"
tools:context=".MapsActivity"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

and the fragment is instantiated by an activity, with:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putSerializable("VEHICLES",_VehiclesList);
fragment_units_map = new VehiclesMapFragment();
_fragment_units_map.setArguments(args);
```

calling _map.animateCamera produce an exception at every  call:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error using newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int): Map size can't be 0. Most likely, layout has not yet occured for the map view. Either wait until layout has occurred or use newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int, int, int) which allows you to specify the map's dimensions.

Comment: As an aside, should consider .getMapAsync() as .getMap() will be deprecated

Comment: I guess you should set the onMapReady listener by adding getMapAsync(this) to OnCreate, otherwise onMapReady will never be called.